# how to get jboss tools to not automatically deploy on server start

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

ive just upgraded to eclipse 3.6 and i have a seam application running on jboss 5 with the latest version of jboss tools.  my problem is that when i opened an xhtml page it asked me to activate the jsf components.  i went ahead and did so and now my problem is that when i start jboss inside of eclipse it automatically deploys an exploded version of my app.  i don't want this, i use ant to build and deploy the app and just use jboss tools to start and stop the server.  i need to turn this feature off, does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Double click the server and select the radiobutton that says "Never publish automatically"

btw. you can also enable "Deploy projects as compressed archives" if your problem is that the deployment is exploded.